# Counting by 10 in java with a while loop

Tags: java

The goal of this code is to count to 50 by 10's but I cant seem to figure out how to do it with a while loop. Would I multiply the integer`ntp` by 10?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in a message, and I'll display it how ever many times you want");
        System.out.print("Message: ");
        String message = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Number of times printed: ");
        int ntp = keyboard.nextInt();

        int n = 10;
        while (n <= ntp) {
            System.out.println(n + ". " + message);
            n += 10; //its the same as "n = n + 1" or "n++"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: okay let me edit the question so its a little more clear

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: is your code not working or what?

Comment: The problem is that I need to print a message five times, tell the code to print the message five times, and have it count by tens, but i cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but this code will print nothing. You tell the program to print some message 5 times but already at the beginning condition in a loop won't be `true`, sice 10 <= 5 is `false`. Why don't you just multiply number, which you give to program by your interval (in this case 10)?

Comment: I think multiplying will get the program to do what im trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingByTens {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Type in a number and we will count by tens." );
    int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

    int n = 10;
    while ( n  <=  inputNumber ) {
       System.out.println( n );
       n += 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is almost the same code as @jackmasterlooter has written, except thee message input part. Althogh he requires to print that message.